# azure function in 'read only mode' - AzureDevops pipeline deployment from zip

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am deploying azure function using Azure Devops pipeline:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-v1?view=azure-pipelines

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy functions to Function App'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: Subscription
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: 'functionX'
              package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/functions.zip
              resourceGroupName: $(resourcegroup)
```

All works great and gets deployed no errors. The problem is the function is never triggered, and the trigger is cron every minute.
There is this message in the azure portal:
`Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting`.

How can I deploy function from Azure Pipelines that can actually work (be triggered)?

Added function code:

```
module.exports = function (context, scaleUpTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    
    if(scaleUpTimer.isPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
    context.done();
};
```

P.S
localized the issue: Had different bindings between manual and automated one.

manual:

```
        "bindings": [
            {
                "name": "myTimer",
                "type": "timerTrigger",
                "direction": "in",
                "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
            }
```

automated:

```
    "bindings": [
        {
            "name": "UpTimerDummy",
            "type": "timerTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
        },
        {
            "type": "queue",
            "name": "operationRequest",
            "queueName": "operations-queue",
            "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
            "direction": "out"
        }
```

My guess is I have no rights to either AzureWebJobsStorage or operations queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out the binding:

```
{
    "type": "queue",
    "name": "operationRequest",
    "queueName": "operations-queue",
    "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "direction": "out"
}
```

was causing this. basically I have some rights issue with this request which causes the function not to invoke. still investigating this, but it is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This deployment task works. Check your deployment result:
[image]

Check your function contents... Additionally, you may run it manually through the Test/Run button:

[image]

Test you function with `async` keyword like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-javascript#example

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.isPastDue)
    {
        context.log('Node is running late!');
    }
    context.log('Node timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
};
```

Comment: Hi Aleksander, I see that your app is in 'read only mode' too. yes it is Timer for me too, but it won't fire. If I go for JSON details: `                {
                    "name": "scaleUpTimer",
                    "type": "timerTrigger",
                    "direction": "in",
                    "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
                }` If I create same manually via portal it works fine...

Comment: @Wojtas.Zet Check your function contents (I`ve updated my answer)... Additionally, you may run it manually through the Test/Run button and check the result in the log window......

Comment: Hi Aleksander, I have no invocations in the monitor either... it won't run via test run, I get unathorized 401...

Comment: OK, so I figured out this so far - have 2 identical time trigger functions, one created 100% manually and it works, second deployed via azure devops as above, I can run the manual one via button with:
HTTP response code
202 Accepted. And the other one deployed via azure pipeline is 401 forbidden. question why?

Comment: @Wojtas.Zet can you test your function with `async` mode? Check this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-javascript#example and this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341523/node-azure-function-timer-trigger-always-timesout

Comment: I have localized the issue. so basically my problem lies here: I had different bindings between my manual function and automated one. I added them at the bottom of question. Having same bindings works just fine.

Comment: I am going to close this question, as it turns out to be the wrong binding. Thank you all for your help!!!